# Overriding interface definitions

Tags: .net, interface-design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is it impossible to override a getter-only property and add a setter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82437/why-is-it-impossible-to-override-a-getter-only-property-and-add-a-setter)

Let's say that I got the following interfaces:

```
public interface IMessage
{
    bool KeepAlive { get; }
}

public interface IRequest : IMessage
{
    bool KeepAlive { get; }
}
```

The problem is that I want the `IReponse` interface to have a setter:

```
public interface IReponse : IMessage
{
    bool KeepAlive { get; set; }
}
```

1. Why isn't that allowed?
2. What kind of problems can I get if I do `new bool KeepAlive { get; set; }`.

**Update:**

I read the other question and it says that it's not expected that the property will change. I do not agree. Let's take for instance `Socket.Connected` property. It has only a getter, but it CAN be changed. What a readonly property says is that the property can only be changed from ***within*** the implementation.

Comment: Have a look at this question/answer, although it focuses mainly VB.NET: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554369/overriding-readonly-property-in-a-subclass-to-make-it-read-write-vb-net/554396#554396

Comment: I agree with jgauffin's update. A get-only property does not imply it will not change.